# Silence `<key> is not defined` notification

Tags: key-bindings

There is a key on my keyboard which I do *not* want to do anything. By default when I press it I get a message in my mini-buffer reading `<cancel> is not defined`. I want to silence that message.

I successfully achieved that with:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<cancel>") (lambda () (interactive)))
```

But wanted to know if there is a more semantic way of achieving this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can bind it to the function `ignore`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<cancel>") #'ignore)
```

Comment: Which is essentially what the OP was doing, just a little more concise.